# Node webkit database support and Browser support

Tags: node-webkit

I am planning to use node webkit for porting my existing html/css/javascript from a web app to desktop native app.Before doing this, i was trying to see if there are any downsides of using node webkit.
Which is the best database supported by nodewkit
My understanding is that it does not require any browser to run this node webkit app and that it provides webkit engine and the app provides a UI to it by using html5, and css.Is this understanding of mine correct?

All your pointers will be helpful.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What server side language are You using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is correct. Node webkit works as an HTML5/Node.js application wrapped around simple browser app written on Chromium Engine, and it doesn't need anything installed to work.

As far as I understand You want to connect to remote database, not create a local one for user data. If that's true, You shouldn't implement it on client side, but on server side. Which means your server side implementation shouldn't differ from Your actual one.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer.I want to store data locally on laptop.I am narrowing down to indexDB because web sql database is depricated.

Comment: If it's locally I'd prefer regular file instead of DB. Node has awesome file management, and it's much less problematic solution.
And because node is single-threaded there is no way for corruption of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

I create some applications with the following struct :

```
- folder : server (for any php/db request or response)

- folder : client (for js/css and images)
```

the relation beetween  the client and the server is AJAX.

and the best db for a local use I prefer : Sqlite (in a network MongoDB or MySQL)
in all the cases it's preferably to use an ORM like Doctrine.

and make sure that in the response of server you send allways a json (not a formatted divs or any html) the client must be able to organise his data him self.

as a sample : openerp use this structure (with python istead of php).

for use of sqlite here is link that explane the way:
http://tejasrpatel.wordpress.com/2011/12/29/create-sqlite-off-line-database-and-insertupdatedeletedrop-operations-in-sqlite-using-jquery-html5-inputs/

that's the advices from my experience. and hope this be helpfull for someone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I want to store data locally on my desktop/laptop. My understanding is that javascript can not access sqlite directly, but i can use indexdb.Hope that is correct...

Comment: take a look at : http://tejasrpatel.wordpress.com/2011/12/29/create-sqlite-off-line-database-and-insertupdatedeletedrop-operations-in-sqlite-using-jquery-html5-inputs/

Answer (score 0):

I am currently developing a node-webkit app myself as well. I had this same question so as I was looking around I found [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/). This looks very promising for a node-webkit environment so that's what I'm going to be using. I hope this helps you out as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is one major part of node-webkit that you don't mention in your question, that is the 'node' part, specifically node.js.  This is important because just about anything you can do in node.js is available to you in node-webkit.

I don't know what your application does, so I can't tell for sure, but you may or may not need an actual database.  If all you want to do is store some data,  you may find a file to be sufficient (JSON or whatever format is convenient for your purpose) which is easy to do with the `fs` module.  Or you might only need to use `localStorage`, which is also available in the 'webkit' part of node-webkit.

If you do actually need a database, then anything works with node.js should be available to you, such as the aforementioned pouchdb, or any number of other possibilities.

In any case, you don't need to set it up as a client server model if you don't want to, you can just access files or databases directly in your node.js code.  Conversely, if you do want to do a client-server model, you can have both running locally within your node-webkit program.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use node-webkit insted of Qt, PySide, etc. and I tell you why:

1. webkit (the most full feature browser)
2. nodejs (what can I say is javascript)
3. cross platform (almost all)

To package and distribuite the software I use [Web2Executable](https://github.com/jyapayne/Web2Executable)

For the GUI I use ExtJs 4.2 from [Sencha](http://sencha.com/)

Database (engine) I use [NeDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) but you can use internal engines from webkit found here [persistent-data-in-app](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Save-persistent-data-in-app)